# Updating a list column thro' a PowerShell script?

Tags: 2007, powershell, development

I have a sharepoint 2007 list and it has many items, I want to update a column in an item thro' a powershell script even if the item is current **edited/locked** by someone else.

Is it posssible?

Answer (score 1):

You can check for the list items File property for check out status, and depending on different conditions check file in or undo checkout (for example undoing checkout when the file has no previous versions will throw an exception, so here it may make more sense to either check in or delete).

Check out the UndoCheckOut() method here
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spfile.undocheckout(v=office.12).aspx

I would definately do this in PowerShell compared to a C# console application. Its much faster once you get the hang of it! In SP2007 theres a little overhead since the cmdlets doesnt exist OOB.

Heres some untested **boilerplate** code (as in: add exceptions and proper checks). Remember you have to dispose the methods you create yourself:

```
[Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("Microsoft.SharePoint")

try
{
    $sites = new-object Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSite("http://extranet.issworld.com/teamrooms/admin")
    $site = $sites.OpenWeb()
    $list = $site.Lists["Documents"];
    if ( $list )
    {
        Write-Host ("Found List [$($list.Title)]")
        $list.Items | Where-Object{$_.File.CheckOutStatus -ne "None"  -and $_.File.CheckedOutBy -ne "domain\myLogin"} | ForEach-Object{$_.File.UndoCheckOut()}

    }

}
finally
{
    if ($sites)
    {
        $sites.Dispose()
    }
    if ($site)
    {
        $site.Dispose() 
    }

}
```

Comment: as i mentioned,its a custom list with few list columns. I wonder if there is a way to find whether the list item is locked using any of its columns except the file field.

Comment: please explan how you defined "item is locked". Do you mean you have enabled approval on the list? (AFAIK there is no checking out of custom list items)

Comment: I am not able to edit/update the item if it is being edited by someone else.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose anything is possible. But it will be quite complicated and probably worse than the equivalent C# code. You will be working directly with the object model, so it might be easier to write a console app in C#.

Comment: ok, but its not allowing me to update the list column if the item is already locked by someone else. Can you suggest me how it can be done using c#?

Comment: yes its a hidden column...